# MongoDb async/insertData, sync/getData: using ReactiveMongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive-programming, webclient, reactive-mongo-java

I have a situation where I need to insert in async and get data (obviously it should be in sync) currenlty am using ReactiveMongoTemplate

```
//insert async
reactiveMongoTemplate.save(MyObject)
```

```
// get data in sync
reactiveMongoTemplate.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("myId")
                .in("myList")), MyObject.class);
```

with above code both are in async

I tried to block `.find` with toIterable() / toStream()

```
reactiveMongoTemplate.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("myId")
                .in("myList")), MyObject.class).toIterable().forEach(myRecord -> {
                    // process response
                });
```

but they are failing with below error

```
Iterating over a toIterable() / toStream() is blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3
```

More code

```
webClient.post()
    .uri("serviceurl")
    .headers("headers")
    .body(Mono.just(body), JsonNode.class)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(MyObject.class)
    .flatMap(responseObject -> {
        Map<String, MySubResponse> repMap = responseObject.
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap("key", "value"));
        reactiveMongoTemplate.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("myId")
                .in("myList")), MyObject.class).toIterable().forEach(val -> {
                        MySubResponse mySubResponse = repMap.get("val.key");
                        mySubResponse.setMyProperty(val.getProperty)
                    }
                });
        return repMap.values();
    });
```

any suggestion on how can I achieve this?

any other alternative?

are should I just use regular mongo template to get details, so results will be in sync, is it a good practise to use ReactiveMongoTemplate and MongoTemplate in a same project ?

Kindly help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

am able to make it work using below code

```
.collectList() // Collects all elements emitted by this Flux into a List 
.toFuture() // waits and returns CompletableFuture
.join(); // return's the data instead of CompletableFuture
```